# If I'm trying to create a Queue in C++, how do I make the Queue of a certain size?

Tags: c++, arrays, queue

I'm very new to C++ and am rather confused as to how to make a Queue (our first homework assignment).

For the constructor, we're supposed to accept a length that the Queue should be. The Queue's length must in turn be the closest Fibonacci number greater than the given length if it is not already a Fibonacci number. (e.g.: if given 10 in the constructor, make the length 13).

Right now I'm implementing the Queue as an array. Should I have something like `int queueContents[];` in the private part of my header, then set it to the closest Fibonacci number in the constructor?

How would I go about declaring it for use throughout the whole file and set its length in my constructor?

Comment: Do you intend to keep it an array? You could use a list and limit the input with a size variable.

Comment: My assignment states to use an array unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have a global variable keep track of the size (if you ever needs to grow it for efficiency's sake).

```
ArrayQueue(int sz) 
{
   size = getFib(sz);
   queueContents = new int[size];
   //set front and back to initial value   
}

getFib(int sz) {...}
```

And yes, you need a global variable `int *queueContents`. (pointer preferred).

Feel free to ask further questions. I recently had to code a basic array-based queue too so (hopefully) I can answer any question you will have. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the nearest fibonacci number and then have a variable `capacity` and everytime you insert into the queue, check if this exceeds the capacity..